# How is $\mathfrak{g} \ltimes_{\mathrm{ad}} \mathfrak{g}$ called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, lie-algebras, semidirect-product

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra.
If $\mathfrak{h}$ is another Lie algebra and $\theta$ is a homomorphism of Lie algebras from $\mathfrak{h}$ to $\operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$, then we can form the semidirect product $\mathfrak{h} \ltimes_\theta \mathfrak{g}$.
As a special case of this construction, one can choose $\mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{g}$ and $\theta = \mathrm{ad}$.

> How is the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} \ltimes_{\mathrm{ad}} \mathfrak{g}$ called?

The same question could be asked about groups, but I also don’t know how the analogous construction for groups is called.

Comment: For groups, $G\rtimes\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is called the holomorph, which contains the subgroup $G\rtimes{\rm Inn}(G)$ which is a quotient of $G\rtimes G$ with the conjugation action (with kernel $Z(G)$ in the right factor). I'm not aware of $G\rtimes G$ having a name, but presumably you could just call ${\frak g}\rtimes {\rm Der}({\frak g})$ a holomorph too.